# Django Rest Framework ordering isnt working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Everything is imported, it might not be working because of get_queryset function, but i am not sure.

```
class ShowStats(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = StatsSerializer

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
    ordering_fields = ('date', 'views', 'clicks', 'cost', 'cpc', 'cpm')
    ordering = ('views',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Stats.objects.filter(date__range=[self.kwargs['from'], self.kwargs['to']])

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        response_list = serializer.data
        for i in range(len(response_list)):
            response_list[i]['cpc'] = response_list[i]['cost'] / response_list[i]['clicks']
            response_list[i]['cpm'] = response_list[i]['cost'] / response_list[i]['views'] * 1000
        return Response(data=response_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
queryset = self.get_queryset()
```

to

```
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```

to apply filtering and/or ordering.

---

Here's what DRF's `ListModelMixin` looks like (for inspiration).

> ```
> class ListModelMixin:
>     """
>     List a queryset.
>     """
>     def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
>         page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
>         if page is not None:
>             serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
>             return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
>
>         serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
>         return Response(serializer.data)
> ```